# SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dt) unexpected errror

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\mohamma ali\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\MyLib_DB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
   string query =  "Select *  From User_Registration where UserID = '" + username_textbox.Text.Trim() + "' & Password = '" + password_text.Text.Trim() + "'";
   SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
   DataTable dt = new DataTable ();
   sda.Fill(dt);

   if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
   {
       mainmenu main = new mainmenu();
       this.Hide();              
       main.Show();
    }
    else
    {
          MessageBox.Show("Please Check usename and password");
    }
}
```

it is returning unexpected error at `sda.fill(dt)`?

Comment: Do not use AttachDbFilename when you are using integrated Security=True.  The SQL serve owns the mdf filename and will not allow access.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683

Comment: Please provide the full error message and details.

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

In SQL you should use `and` instead of `&`.  Also you should always use [parameterized queries](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So your query should be something like this:

```
  string query =  "Select *  From User_Registration where UserID = @userName and Password = @password";
  sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName ", username_textbox.Text.Trim());
  sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password_text.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        string commandText = "Select * From User_Registration where UserID = @UserID  and Password = @Password ";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\mohamma ali\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication4\WindowsFormsApplication4\MyLib_DB.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", username_textbox.Text.Trim());
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password_text.Text.Trim());

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                sda.SelectCommand = command;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    mainmenu main = new mainmenu();
                    this.Hide();
                    main.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Check usename and password");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```